# Need to write a Python script to automate drag & drop

Tags: python, ole

I need to write a Python script that DROPs a given filename, onto an existing Window HWND.

This third-pardy HWND accepts only OLE drops (not Paste, nor Dropfile).  Sort of an automated drag & drop.  This is for Windows 7.

I've tried bunches of things, but am getting nowhere.  Not even sure this is possible. I've been able to do this with older Windows that accept Dropfile, but OLE has me stumped. Any advice or pointers appreciated.